# How to use non 22 ssh port in visual studio code insiders remote developments?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

ssh login by authentication is working fine.

```
C:\Users\${DEVELOPER_NAME}>ssh ${HOST_IP_ADDRESS} -l ${DEVELOPER_NAME} -p ${SSHD_PORT} -i D:\prefix\PuTTY\${OPENSSH_FORMAT_PRIVATE_KEY}
Last login: Sun May  5 15:27:50 2019 from 10.40.171.44
Welcome to ...
[${DEVELOPER_NAME}@${HOST_AKA} ~]$
```

but sshd is running on 36000 not default 22 port, how can I tell that to vs code remote-ssh plugin

```
Host ${DEVELOPER_NAME}@${HOST_IP_ADDRESS}
HostName ${HOST_IP_ADDRESS}:${SSHD_PORT}
User ${DEVELOPER_NAME}
Port ${SSHD_PORT}
IdentityFile D:\prefix\PuTTY\${OPENSSH_FORMAT_PRIVATE_KEY}
```

this way gives me

```
Can't connect to ${DEVELOPER_NAME}@${HOST_IP_ADDRESS}: unreachable or not Linux x86_64 (ssh: connect to host ${HOST_IP_ADDRESS} port 22: Connection refused)
```

and

```
${DEVELOPER_NAME}@${HOST_IP_ADDRESS}:${SSHD_PORT}
```

in `Remote-SSH: Connect to Host...` gives me

```
Can't connect to ${DEVELOPER_NAME}@${HOST_IP_ADDRESS}:${SSHD_PORT}: unreachable or not Linux x86_64 (ssh: Could not resolve hostname ${HOST_IP_ADDRESS}:${SSHD_PORT}: Name or service not known)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your question, I solved it. You may have already figured it out ... You do not need to add a port for HostName. Just write Port and it works.

```
Host ${HOST_NICKNAME}
    User ${USER_ID_HOST}
    HostName ${HOST_IP_ADDRESS}
    Port ${SSHD_PORT}
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa-remote-ssh
```